# Not able to fetch data from one spring boot to another using url (microservices)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, rest

MovieCatalogResource.java

```
package io.javabrains.moviecatalogservice.resources;

import java.util.Arrays;
//import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import io.javabrains.moviecatalogservice.models.CatalogItem;
import io.javabrains.moviecatalogservice.models.Movie;
import io.javabrains.moviecatalogservice.models.Rating;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogResource {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        
        List<Rating> ratings = Arrays.asList(
            
                new Rating("abcd",5),
                new Rating("bcde",5)
                
        );
        
        return ratings.stream().map(rating -> {
            Movie movie = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/movies/" + rating.getMovieId(), Movie.class);
            return new CatalogItem(movie.getName(),"desc",rating.getRating());
        
        })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
//      return Collections.singletonList(new CatalogItem("Transformers","test",4)
    //          );
        
        
    }
        
}
```

MovieResource.java

```
package io.javabrains.movieinfoservice.resources;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.javabrains.movieinfoservice.models.Movie;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieResource {
    
    @RequestMapping("/{movieId}")
    public Movie getMovieInfo(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {
        
        return new Movie(movieId,"Test name");
        
    }

}
```

Error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8082/movies/abcd": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect] with root cause.

```
As you can see i am not able to fetch data from MovieResource.java to MovieCatalogResource.java using url.it is showing me the above error in console and,

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

showing this error in chrome.
```

Comment: Are you sure that MovieResource service running on port number 8082.  http://localhost:8082/movies/5 execute this on browser after  running the MovieResource application.

Comment: yes , i check thrice , i also checked by changing port numbers, i did everything , but nothing works

Comment: Replace request mapping to @GetMapping("/api/{movieid}").  all in lower case. And check what port which application running by checking the logs.

Comment: if i do getmapping , i am having a error

Comment: Try this::    @GetMapping("/{movieId}")
@ResponseBody
 public Movie getMovieInfo(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {        
        return new Movie(movieId,"Test name");        
    }